# LInker error when switching from windows to console

Tags: qt, visual-c++, waf, subsystem

I am using Qt for GUI and building my project in waf.
For switching to windows subsystem from console(default) i had to pass this argument to the VS linker throught my wscript(waf)

```
subsystem='windows'
```

i added this in build part for waf file and I am getting this error

```
MSVCRT.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
C:\cygwin\home\sobingt\project\build\src\View\app.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I want to run this program as windows not as console.The Code works if i run it as console

```
subsystem='console'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link against `qtmain.lib` (IIRC). This provides a shim around `winmain` which you need for windowed windows apps.

Comment: I am not at home to look it up. But it should be included with your Qt distribution in the same folder where QtCore.lib an QtMain.lib are. I don't really remember how to input it in a pro file though.

Comment: Its called qtmain.lib it's still there in my qt4.8. Just add it to the linker like you would any other qt component.